# Counting the number of controls in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android, right now I am trying to find a way to get the number of controls (I don't know how to call these in android, I mean like I have 4 textviews, 2 edittexts, 3 buttons so in total I have 9 "controls"), is there any way to count them?

Comment: View containers have getChildCount() function. So you just apply to your container and...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're called Views in Android. Yes, even the buttons. You can use getChildCount() but you'd have to do it recursively if you have views inside views. What I would do is get your base view and then use something like:

```
public int getViewCount(View view) {
    int viewCount = 1;
    if(view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        viewCount += countChildren((ViewGroup)view);
    }
    return viewCount;
}

public int countChildren(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int viewCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
        viewCount += getViewCount(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
    }
    return viewCount;
}
```

What complicates things is the fact that only ViewGroups can have children, but Buttons and stuff are instances of View but not of ViewGroup.

If you don't want it to count ViewGroups, try this:

```
public int getViewCount(View view) {
    int viewCount = 1;
    if(view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        viewCount = 0;  // Uncounts for ViewGroups, but still checks them for Views.
        viewCount += countChildren((ViewGroup)view);
    }
    return viewCount;
}

public int countChildren(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int viewCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
        viewCount += getViewCount(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
    }
    return viewCount;
}
```

Comment: Nice code! I think it might be even better (for suitable values of _better_!) with indirect recursion, with `getChildren()` calling back to `getViewCount()` rather than passing back an array of Views.

Comment: hi Kyuubi, I try your code and I change it a little bit as you say, it has to be viewGroup to have getChildCount so I use this instead:
    
    public int countChildren(View view) {
        int viewCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount(); i++){
            viewCount += getViewCount(((ViewGroup)view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        return viewCount;
    }
However, there is a small proble, it does not only call count my buttons and textviews but also count my layout, can I just force it to count my buttons and textviews only? Thanks.